# Adding JSON field to Django Activity Stream results in unknown column error, even with django-jsonfield installed

Tags: django

I need to use django-activity-stream and it would be really helpful to be able to use the extra "data" field, to attach extra information about the nature of the actions listed.

According to the documentation it should be quite simple to get up and running: http://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data.html#custom-data

I installed django-jsonfield, changed the settings to match, and tried to start using it, but here is the error I get

`Unknown column 'actstream_action.data' in 'field list'`

Here is more information, in case it helps:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/actstream/action/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 2.7.8
Installed Applications:
('django_admin_bootstrapped',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'timezone_field',
 'storages',
 'mathfilters',
 'adminactions',
 'challenges',
 'social',
 'management',
 'actstream',
 'notifications')
Installed Middleware:
('ssl_redirect.middleware.SSLRedirectMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
 'project.middlewares.TimezoneMiddleware',
 'project.middlewares.CampaignsMiddleware',
 'project.middlewares.AccountMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py" in changelist_view
  1638.             media = self.media + formset.media
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in media
  391.         if self.forms:
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in __get__
  60.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in forms
  142.         forms = [self._construct_form(i) for i in range(self.total_form_count())]
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in total_form_count
  117.             initial_forms = self.initial_form_count()
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/models.py" in initial_form_count
  567.             return len(self.get_queryset())
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in __len__
  144.         self._fetch_all()
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _fetch_all
  965.             self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in iterator
  238.         results = compiler.execute_sql()
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  829.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  124.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  205.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/tmp/project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/actstream/action/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'actstream_action.data' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: Have you run database migrations ?

Comment: I should have mentioned that. Yes I did. Running migrations after switching on JSON field simply told me there were no migrations to apply.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem. The solution was to rerun the migrations. In my case it is easy to say - I did not have any data yet. For some of you data backup and recovery may be necessary.

To revert the actstream migrations:
`python manage.py migrate actstream zero`
and then:
`python manage.py migrate actstream`

Of course it works if you have `django-jsonfield` installed.